# Applying rules of linear operators to expectation in probability

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory

**The Question:**

Given: $X_1, X_2, Y$ are random variables where $X_1,X_2$ are independent and $X_1$ and $Y=X_1+X_2$ have poisson distribution with $\mu_1$ and $\mu$ respectively, such that $\mu \gt \mu_1$.

Find: The distribution of $X_2$.

**My Work:**

The MGF of $Y$ is $$e^{\mu(e^t-1)}=E(e^{ty})=E(e^{t(x_1+x_2)})=E(e^{tx_1}e^{tx_2})$$

Now, because I've seen it done before, I think the next step is that $E(e^{tx_1}e^{tx_2})=E(e^{tx_1})E(e^{tx_2})$, but I can't justify it. I know that the properties of linear operators only talk about scalar multiplication and and addition/subtraction.

What is the missing link?

Comment: @novavita Yes, that is correct. Y is the sum.

Comment: You have to use the independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$...